# How does the total kinetic energy of a moving rigid body decompose when the instantaneous center of rotation is used?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

When using the center of mass CM, the kinetic energy of a moving body is expressed as a simple sum of the kinetic energy of the CM plus the rotational energy about the CM. In dynamics, the CM is a very useful point.

What if we used the center of instantaneous rotation (CIR) instead of the CM? How would the expression for the total kinetic energy of a rigid body look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Total kinetic energy of the system if instantaneous center of rotation is used is given by:- $$K=\frac{1}{2}I_{CIR}\omega^2$$ where,

$I_{CIR}=$ Moment of inertia of the system about the instantaneous center of rotation.

$\omega=$ Angular velocity of the system about the instantaneous center of rotation.

We can write this because we can assume pure rotational motion of the system taking place about the instantaneous center of rotation. Moreover, it is equal to total kinetic energy of the system calculated by using the center of mass. So, therefore we can write:- $$K=\frac{1}{2}mv_{CM}^2+\frac{1}{2}I_{CM}\omega^2=\frac{1}{2}I_{CIR}\omega^2$$

Hope it helps.

Comment: I see. that is even more streamlined than when we use the CM.  I thought that in dynamics, the CM was generally a better choice, better than the CIR which seems more useful in kinematics.